# How to create Transparent panel in c#.Net

Tags: c#, panel

I have a Panel on windows Form with few controls inside panel,

Can i make panel completely transparent.

(It should give the feel that controls are placed directly on Form)

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by transparent? Do you mean Aero level of Transparency?

Comment: I don't know what is Aero level of Transparency is, panel should not be visible to the enduser,he should feel that controls on the panel are on Form

Comment: I meant Aero Glass http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you go to the BackColor property, and change the Selector to "Web" the first choice is Transparent (at least it is in my VB IDE). I believe that the BackColor of the Panel would inherit the color of the component it is on.

Comment: does this show the underneath through? as im trying to do that and this doesnt seem to work?

Comment: No, this does not show what is underneath.  I too need the panel to be truly transparent so the map beneath the panel can be seen.  What I get now is a great big gray box on top of my map with controls.  I need it to be transparent - not to take the color of the form beneath it (which isn't visible since I'm showing a map.)

Answer (score 3):

I assume it is WinForms app.

Try this in Form.Load event:

```
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

where panel1 is the panel you want to have transparent.

It will make the color transparent. You can have other controls on the panel.