# Little warning message on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, warnings

I have a textbox that's really only supposed to take so many characters, but it can take more if it needs to. What I'd like to do is have a small little message window pop up when the user passes a certain number of characters. I know how to trigger an event when the user passes however-many characters, but I don't know how to make a little warning window come up.

Theres `MessageBox`, but it's a little big and bulky for what I need. I'm imagining a small white or yellow bubble coming up, and then slowly fading away, I know I've seen it before, I just don't know what it's called, or how to create one in C#.

If anyone knows the name of what I'm thinking of and how to make it in winforms, or an alternative, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `ToolTip` class. You can use the function `Show` to trigger it. Take a look at this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx

[image: ToolTip component]

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of, thank you! It's hard to say what I want when I don't know the name of it, but I did my best to describe it.

Comment: Good Nathan, you can mark this question as correct to help future developers.

Answer (score 0):

1- add panel with button for closing this panel

2- set it's visibility to hidden

3- add a label in panel

4- type your message in this label

5- you can adjust and [draw shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312413/how-to-draw-shapes-in-panels-of-windows-form) with your selected color in the panel

6- you can [set transparency to this panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722319/how-to-create-transparent-panel-in-c-net) without the shape you draw

7- finally you'll see a beautiful message box